# string.Join in Linq to Entity queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm currently shifting my data access code from L2S to Entity framework db first. I have problem with queries like following

```
var emps = (from emp in DataContext.setupEmployees
                       let contacts = DataContext.setupContacts.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == emp.EmployeeID).Select(x => x.Contact)
                       select new 
                       {
                           EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName,
                           Contacts = string.Join(", ", contacts.ToArray())
                       }).ToList();
```

EF tells me it can't convert the method `string.join` into stored expression. One obvious work-around is to bring the objects in memory (ToList, AsEnumerable etc) and then call `string.Join` method like

```
var emps = (from emp in DataContext.setupEmployees
                       let contacts = DataContext.setupContacts.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == emp.EmployeeID).Select(x => x.Contact)
                       select new 
                       {
                           EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName,
                           Contacts = contacts
                       }).ToList().Select(x=>new{
                            x.EmployeeName,
                            Contacts = string.Join(", ",x.Contacts)
                       });
```

This solution works perfectly but it's just that it's more verbose and I'd have to duplicate select clause in lots of queries that used to work fine in L2S.

**My question:** is there any way I can avoid writing this `ToList` thing and call `string.Join` and similar methods in EF query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215066/entity-framework-with-linq-aggregate-to-concatenate-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095658/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-entity-framework-query

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating `Contacts` as an `IEnumerable<string>` datatype instead of `string` datatype. You can than use `Contacts` to produce any output you like comma seperated etc...

You can change your query to look like this:

```
var emps = (from emp in DataContext.setupEmployees
            select new 
            {
              EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName,
              Contacts = DataContext.setupContacts.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == emp.EmployeeID).Select(x => x.Contact)
            }).ToList();
```