# How to String Array convert String Value, in linq line?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I used string.join but not working.

```
 IQueryable<CandidateVModel> list = cRepository.Table.Where(x=> !x.CFDemand.Any(y => y.AStatusId == (int) TStatus.SWork)).Select(x => new CandidateVModel
        {
            ...
            Email = x.Email,
            Tags = x.Tags,
            Comments= string.Join(", ",x.CFDemand.SelectMany(y=>y.JInterview.SelectMany(z=>z.JInterviewer.SelectMany(t=>t.JInterviewerFeedback.Select(a=>a.Comments))))),
            Ref= x.Ref
        }).AsExpandable().Where(p);
```

Error:Message = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: That needs to be seriously re-thought.... I got lost after the first select many let alone the next 3. This is a code smell to me...

Comment: There's no SQL equivalent to `String.Join`so EF cannot translate that to SQL.  If you can provide more detail as to your data model you may get some help pulling both sets and joining them in Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: refer below link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095658/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-entity-framework-query

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too much into this, one way to resolve `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method` issues is to simplify what you're getting from the database, and create a helper property on your viewmodel like so:

```
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> CommentsFromDb
    {
        set
        {
            Comments = string.Join(", ", value);
        }
    }
```

`[IgnoreDataMember]` will keep this helper property from getting serialized.

And update your code snippit to be this:

```
...
CommentsFromDb = x.CFDemand.SelectMany(y=>y.JInterview.SelectMany(z=>z.JInterviewer.SelectMany(t=>t.JInterviewerFeedback.Select(a=>a.Comments))))
```